# how to get a list of file ids of the google drive directory,

Tags: python

I'm trying to download files from a specific google drive folder. I couldn't download the folder directly, but I got an error saying that only binary files can be downloaded this way. Then I tried to get the file IDs of a specific folder and download them in a loop. Here is the code that I tried to use to get the folder file ids:

```
def make_conect():
    CLIEN_SECRET_FILE = 'client_secret_844464197570-vh4is72q90s1qmoc2pbgmk8r9vlhv61m.apps.googleusercontent.com.json'
    API_NAME = 'drive'
    API_VERSION = 'v3'
    SCOPES = ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive']
    service = Create_Service(CLIEN_SECRET_FILE, API_NAME, API_VERSION, SCOPES)
    return service

def video_direct(service):
    file_metadata = {
    'name': 'users video',
    'mimeType': 'application/vnd.google-apps.folder'
     }
    file = service.files().create(body=file_metadata,
                                fields='id').execute()
     print(file.get('id'))

def user_video_direct(service, user_id):
    parents = '1NH0qxXkAuX7L4ETd3cp0Un5cBDOLXYIg'
    dir_name = 'video_user_' + str(user_id)
    file_metadata = {
    'name': dir_name,
    'mimeType': 'application/vnd.google-apps.folder',
    'parents': [parents]
     }
    file = service.files().create(body=file_metadata,
                              fields='id').execute()
    return  file.get('id')
    service = make_conect()


file_list = service.ListFile(
{'q': "'1R6eT6NE19_9LshSK3FsIHMVY6KOkhrG2' in parents"}).GetList()
```

the error I'm getting:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "D:\pythonProject1\google.py", line 148, in <module>
file_list = service.ListFile(
AttributeError: 'Resource' object has no attribute 'ListFile'
```

how can I fix it or download files from a specific folder?

**updating the question:**

I use a function that contains build in itself:

```
def Create_Service(client_secret_file, api_name, api_version, *scopes):
print(client_secret_file, api_name, api_version, scopes, sep='-')
CLIENT_SECRET_FILE = client_secret_file
API_SERVICE_NAME = api_name
API_VERSION = api_version
SCOPES = [scope for scope in scopes[0]]
print(SCOPES)

cred = None

pickle_file = f'token_{API_SERVICE_NAME}_{API_VERSION}.pickle'
# print(pickle_file)

if os.path.exists(pickle_file):
    with open(pickle_file, 'rb') as token:
        cred = pickle.load(token)

if not cred or not cred.valid:
    if cred and cred.expired and cred.refresh_token:
        cred.refresh(Request())
    else:
        flow = InstalledAppFlow.from_client_secrets_file(CLIENT_SECRET_FILE, SCOPES)
        cred = flow.run_local_server()

    with open(pickle_file, 'wb') as token:
        pickle.dump(cred, token)

try:
    service = build(API_SERVICE_NAME, API_VERSION, credentials=cred)
    print(API_SERVICE_NAME, 'service created successfully')
    return service
except Exception as e:
    print('Unable to connect.')
    print(e)
    return None
```

all classes are used from the documentation

Comment: I don't see Resource class in your code, you are facing this error because the application cant find ListFile inside Resource, Please include more code by hiding the authentication variables and drive names. That would be helpful to understand the issue

Comment: @Santhosh Reddy  I added some more code. And there are definitely files in the folder. I manually added them there specifically to check the operation of the function

Comment: from the  [google docs](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/quickstart/python) i understand that we have to use `build` for service, try using `build` instead of `Create_Service` for `service`, please let me know if you are using other drive API.

Comment: @Santhosh Reddy I added more information to the question, responding to your comment